# Accidentally released iOS app in debug mode

Tags: ios, release

I released an iOS app yesterday, mistakenly still in debug mode. If I send an incremental update in release mode, will it create a new version on users' devices?

Edit: The version that's currently live (but in debug mode) has the bundle ID "com.myCompany.myApp". I want to submit an update (in release mode) with the exact same bundle ID, and then append "-test" to the debug mode version.

Comment: What do you mean by incremental update?

Comment: @trojanfoe The version in debug mode that's currently live is 1.0; I simply want to release a 1.01 in release mode, but want to ensure it will overwrite my users' current version, rather than installing a new app on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep the same bundle identifier (usually of the form `com.company.appname`), it will be a simple update. There can't be two different apps with the same bundle identifier on a device (neither on the AppStore by the way).

Comment: Just to be certain: I renamed my debug build to append "-test" to the bundle identifier, and the release build now has the original identifier. Can you confirm that the release build will simply take the place of the currently-live debug build?

Comment: If you appended `-test` to the bundle identifier you have to keep it in your bundle ID. The only way to remove it is to remove the app from the App Store and create a new app with the right bundle identifier.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. The currently-live version on the App Store does **not** have "-test" appended to it. So the update I want to send out **will** have the same bundle ID as the currently-live version. Can you confirm or deny your last comment?

Comment: If your update has the same bundle identifier, it will go live as an update to current users.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the bundle identifier. You should release a newer version of your app in the release mode. This will let the users update their app to your newer version which will be in release.